# How to separate single json object into two json object based on json string values using java?

Tags: java, android, json

I here by mentioned the sample json object.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "sql",
    "age": 30,
    "car": "car",
    "office": "office",
    "cancel": "CANCEL",
    "ok": "OK"
    "cancel": "Anulo",
    "language": "en",
    "remove": "Remove",
    "ignore": "Ignore",
    "image_list": "Image List",
    "block": "Block",
    "loading": "Loading...",
    "splash_screen": "Splash Screen",
    "save": "Save",
    "skip": "Skip",
    "off": "Off",
    "vibration": "Vibration",
    "downloading": "Downloading...",
    "fix_it": "Fix it!"

}
```

Like above JSON object in my JSON object have **more than 500 JSON string** values. How to separate single json object into two json object based on json string values?

**FIRST JSON OBJECT**

```
 {
    "id": "1",
    "age": 30,
    "office": "office"
    "cancel": "Anulo",
    "remove": "Remove",
    "image_list": "Image List",
    "loading": "Loading...",
    "save": "Save",
    "fix_it": "Fix it!"
    }
```

**SECOND JSON OBJECT**

```
{ 
"name": "sql",
"car": "car",
"cancel": "CANCEL",
"ok": "OK"
"language": "en",
"ignore": "Ignore",
"block": "Block",
"splash_screen": "Splash Screen",
"skip": "Skip",
"off": "Off",
"vibration": "Vibration",
"downloading": "Downloading...",
}
```

Comment: what kind of pattern is here to split json objects? it seems very hard coded.

Comment: parse the first json and then add them into individual json objects, as you don't seem to have any pattern for dividing them

Comment: Need to split some JSON string based on the key value , that value is mingled with that single JSON . @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: Since there is no definite pattern, You can split them as two JSON Object based on the length, after parsing (JSON string) it as JSON Array.

Answer (score 0):

it have a pattern? or it's just a random object?

Comment: It is just a random object

Answer (score -1):

I don't know its good way or bad.

Create Two Model class.

**Class A**

```
package com.test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class A {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;
@SerializedName("office")
@Expose
private String office;
@SerializedName("cancel")
@Expose
private String cancel;
@SerializedName("remove")
@Expose
private String remove;
@SerializedName("image_list")
@Expose
private String imageList;
@SerializedName("loading")
@Expose
private String loading;
@SerializedName("save")
@Expose
private String save;
@SerializedName("fix_it")
@Expose
private String fixIt;

//Getter Setter for all members...

}
```

**Class B**

```
package com.test;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class B {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("car")
@Expose
private String car;
@SerializedName("cancel")
@Expose
private String cancel;
@SerializedName("ok")
@Expose
private String ok;
@SerializedName("language")
@Expose
private String language;
@SerializedName("ignore")
@Expose
private String ignore;
@SerializedName("block")
@Expose
private String block;
@SerializedName("splash_screen")
@Expose
private String splashScreen;
@SerializedName("skip")
@Expose
private String skip;
@SerializedName("off")
@Expose
private String off;
@SerializedName("vibration")
@Expose
private String vibration;
@SerializedName("downloading")
@Expose
private String downloading;

 //Getter Setter for all members...

}
```

Now use Google GSON library to parse

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String mainJson="put your main JSON here"

A a = gson.fromJson(json, A.class);
B b = gson.fromJson(json, B.class);
```